# Re-Merge El Capitan Recovery with Original Mac OS

Tags: fusion-drive, macos

Due to recent partitioning mistakes I was unable to boot up my Mac OSX or my Bootcamp on my Mac since. As a last resort I went to recovery mode and downloaded a new El Capitan OS.

Unfortunately this OS created its own partition. Once I was able to delete the problem partitions, I found I no longer needed the El Capitan Recovery partition.

I am looking for a safe way to merge my Fusion Drives back to 1 whole partition, preferably without losing any of the data on my original Mac OS X.

Comment: I have not yet merged the drives but currently, I am able to only access Bootcamp on the Mac, even when I hold the ALT button on boot. I have been unable to access neither of the Mac OS but I can access the Mac Terminal via recovery mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "safe" way to do this.  Creating or destroying a Fusion Drive is a destructive process.

Having the recovery partition is normally a desirable thing, was there a particular reason you did not want it?

If you do no want to create a Fusion Drive again you will need to ensure you have a full backup.  You will need to boot from a USB installer, see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372) on how to create one.

If you open Disk Utility when booted from the USB installer and it detects an SSD and HDD installed it may offer to create the Fusion Drive for you automatically.  If not there are instructions [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-how-to-create-and-disable-a-fusion-drive/) on creating one manually.

Once the Fusion Drive has been created you can proceed with the normal installation.

Note that if using Boot Camp Windows will only reside on the mechanical drive not the SSD so will not enjoy of the benefits of a Fusion Drive.  It is specified in Apple's support [article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204990).